# What is the use of secret_key_base in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

I am new to Rails 4, and do not understand the use of `secret_key_base` under `config/secrets.yml` in Rails 4. Can you please explain this concept?

Also, when I am working in the production environment, I am prompted to set the `secret_key` with `devise.rb`, `config.secret_key`, and `secret_key_base`. However, I can generate a new secret using the `rake secret` command.

What is the difference between development and production environments?

How is it matching the newly generated `secret_key` when I add it with `secret_key_base` every time I generate?

How is it securing the application with other servers?

Comment: For readers using Ruby on Rails 5.2 or newer. `secret_key_base` is still used but stored in `config/credentials.yml.enc` instead. This file is encrypted. You can find more info about the new credential system [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#custom-credentials), or run `rails credentials:help`.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The `secret_token.rb` file's content includes a long randomized string ***which is used to verify the integrity of signed cookies*** (such as user sessions when people are signed into your web app).

[Documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html) says:

> Use your existing secret_key_base from the `secret_token.rb` initializer
>   to set the SECRET_KEY_BASE environment variable for whichever users
>   run the Rails app in production mode. Alternately, you can simply copy the existing secret_key_base from the `secret_token.rb` initializer to secrets.yml under the production section, replacing `<%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>`.

Since it is important file, and you can't put it to .gitignore, it is treated to be a good practice to use env variable to store `secret_key_base` value:

create `.env` or `.powenv` file and store it as:

```
export SECRET_TOKEN="9489b3eee4eccf317ed77407553e8adc97baca7c74dc7ee33cd93e4c8b69477eea66eaedeb18af0be2679887c7c69c0a28c0fded0a71ea472a8c4laalal19cb"
```

And then in `config/initializers/secret_token.rb`

```
YourAppName::Application.config.secret_key_base = if Rails.env.development? or Rails.env.test? # generate simple key for test and development environments
  ('a' * 30) # should be at least 30 chars long
else
  ENV['SECRET_TOKEN']
end
```

[This article](http://daniel.fone.net.nz/blog/2013/05/20/a-better-way-to-manage-the-rails-secret-token/)  is (a bit old and) long but really full of useful info on the topic.

---

## UPDATE 04.05.15

Starting from Rails 4.2 there is no longer `secret_token.rb` file.
By new convention there is a `config/secrets.yml` file aimed to store application's secrets.

[Have a read](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#config-secrets-yml) on how to upgrade an existing app to 4.2.x according to innovations.

---

Technically the purpose of `secrect_key_base` is to be the secret input for the application’s `key_generator` method (check `Rails.application.key_generator`).

The application’s `key_generator`, and thus `secret_key_base`, are used by three core features within the Rails framework:

- Deriving keys for encrypted cookies which are accessible via
  `cookies.encrypted`.
- Deriving the key for HMAC signed cookies which are
  accessible via `cookies.signed`.
- Deriving keys for all of the
  application’s named [`message_verifier`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Application.html#method-i-message_verifier) instances.

Check out more on each of the three in the [article by @michaeljcoyne](https://medium.com/@michaeljcoyne/understanding-the-secret-key-base-in-ruby-on-rails-ce2f6f9968a1).

Comment: Note if you are using something like Ansible or similar to deploy you can replace the entire secret.yml during production deployment and gitignore `config/secret.yml` if you prefer.

Comment: Actually, config/secrets.yml is introduced since Rails 4.1

Comment: All this means when you change `secret_key_base`, your users get logged out. At least.

Answer (score 28):

#### secret_key_base is used to encrypt and sign session

#### in order to safely send session back and forth in cookies

---

In **Rails 4**,

1. if your app is called `Hello`, and
2. you set `session['a'] = 'b'`,

your cookie will look something like this:

```
_Hello_session=BAh7B0kiD3%3D%3D--dc40a55cd52fe32bb3b84ae0608956dfb5824689
```

which translates into:

```
_Hello_session=<encrypted a=b>--<digital signature>
```

Cookies are set by server and kept client side, with browser resending set cookies to the server every time we request a page.

To prevent evil people from understanding `a=b` string, it's **encrypted**.
To prevent evil people from tampering cookies, **digital signature** is used.

In both cases **secret_key_base** value is used (to encrypt/decrypt a=b and to validate digital signature).

Comment: 1. as I know session data is saved in the server and there is a session_id in cookie. eg. store user_id in a session, the only session_id can be seen by the browser while once login the server can know which user send the request by session_id. Here you say session['a'] = 'b' will encrypt the data inside cookie. I am not sure if you are confused between session and cookie. 2. how can a browser decrypt it without know the secret_key_base and get the information?

Comment: sorry, now I know rails is using cookie-based session, which means the session infomation is stored inside cookies.

Comment: yes that's correct, cookie-based sessions offer portability for sessions in distributed app servers and speed